# How to set minimum output file size of spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to get data from Kafka using Spark Structured Streaming.
I want output file size to be about 20 MB.
Since I am using `latest` for `startingoffset` option when reading from Kafka, most of files' size are about 230 KB.
How can I make all output files **bigger** than 20MB?
I even used `maxpffsetpertrigger` option as `100000000`, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think this question is similar to "how many records to read from a topic to reach 20MB size"? How would you do that? I think if you could do that in Kafka itself (with Kafka Consumer API) there could be a way in Spark too. I doubt it's possible though.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski When I use `latest` option, initially gotten data are less than 1MB, but soon, data gonna be bigger than 10MB. Some data are bigger than 30MB. And I guess, it's because of `maxoffsetpertrigger=10000000`, but it takes some time for data to be bigger.

Answer (score -1):

maxOffsetsPerTrigger property specifies offsets processed per trigger interval and nothing about size while writing your data, as per documentation

> Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger interval. The specified total number of offsets will be proportionally split across topicPartitions of different volume.

Use coalesce(numPartitions) to repartition your data and decrease number of partitions as per your requirement(if already doing so and not working please provide some code). As per spark documentation:

> Decrease the number of partitions in the RDD to numPartitions. Useful for running operations more efficiently after filtering down a large dataset.

Comment: How does this answer help with _"I want output file size to be about 20 MB."_?